# Ways to dynamically enable/disable debug features in an APK

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I'm developing an APK. I'd like to be able to set and unset various options for debugging purposes. For example:

- Enable a time profile trace
- Enable some experimental feature
- Enable very verbose output to logcat
- ...

Currently, we do this by creating a flag in our code for each feature and set/unsetting it. However:

- is time consuming because of the need to rebuild, upload and relaunch the APK
- runs the risk of people accidentally checking things in in a debug mode state
- requires a rebuild of the APK -- we can't ask our customers to enable a debugging feature and report the results.

Is there a pattern that Android developers follow solve this kind of problem?

In the past, we've used environment variables for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the debugging permission [SET_DEBUG_APP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_DEBUG_APP) in your apk. Create a new class called

```
class MYLog {
i(String Tag, String msg) {
  if(LOG_ENABLED){
  Log.i(TAG, msg);
}
```

You may call the MyLog.i instead of Log.i(). You may get the LOG_ENABLED value from the server to enable/disable logging.

Comment: Can I then disable the debugging output without rebuilding, uploading and relaunching the APK?

Comment: Yes, you can disable it in the server. You won't need to create another apk file. Whenever app is started, it will get the LOG_ENABLED flag from the server to determine the log enable/disable the status. You will need the permission to read the logs from the app and send it to server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider doing it one of two ways, depending on how much of this feature you want to expose to your users:

- Key the debug features off of SharedPreference values, and expose them in a preferences/debug menu in the UI.
- Use the presence/contents of a file in external storage where you can email the file to & instruct an end user where to place it to enable the debug features.

Option 2 is not much different a notion than using environment variables.